# What is the meaning of the Legend values for DensityHistogram and SmoothDensityHistogram?

Tags: plotting, histograms

I generate some random 2D data points, then look at the histogram in three different ways.

```
dataf = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {200, 2}];

Histogram3D[dataf, 5]

DensityHistogram[dataf, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 400, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Right]]

SmoothDensityHistogram[dataf, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 400, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, 
    LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.3], 10, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], 
   After]]
```

[image]

The values along the z-axis for the `Histogram3D` are easy enough to understand, they are the bin heights.  But what are the meanings for the values in the `DensityHistogram` legend?  I would expect it to be related to the first plot like `DensityPlot` is related to `Plot3D`.  But the values are wildly different.

And the `SmoothDensityHistogram` is even more different.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you asking.

Comment: The values for `DensityHistogram` and `Histogram3D` are the same, but you aren't using the same number of bins for both.

Comment: "`SmoothDensityHistogram[data]` by default generates colorized grayscale output of the PDF of {{$x_1$, $y_1$}, ...}, based on a smooth kernel density estimate."